# gitHub remove upstream after forking

Tags: git, github

I have forked a project into a different space. I would like to unlink the upstream because we are seeing a lot of commits.

After forking, git remote -v does not show the upstream branches

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To remove the upstream for the current branch, you can run:

```
$ git branch --unset-upstream
```

I also recommend running the following commands:

```
git config --unset branch.<branch>.remote
git config --unset branch.<branch>.merge
```

This will update the configuration for the local branch.